# Unable to access Azure SQL Server from my Azure VM SSMS

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, ssms-2016

I'm getting the message when I attempt to access the my SQL Server from SSMS

> Cannot connect to xxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net.
>
> Cannot open server 'xxxxxxxx' requested by the login. Client is not allowed to access the server. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 40914)

Can someone let me know what are the possible causes?

Comment: Why are you using SSMS 2016, out of interest, and not the latest version?

Comment: Azure SQL Database has a firewall: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure?view=azuresql

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just figured it out.

I needed to add my VM to the firewall Doh!

BTW, I'm using SSMS 18.12, not 16 as originally posted. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to repro the problem, and it worked for me.**

1. Check the DNS label virtual machine and check the properties of it. Select the SQL server VM
2. Select the **Public IP address**

[image]

3. Click on the **Configurations** in the **Public IP Address**
4. Assign a name of the DNS label

[image]

5. Open SSME and click on **Connect in Object Explorer**
6. Click on **Database Engine**

[image]

7. Give the following information required:

- Server type
- Server name
- Authentication
- Login
- Password

8. Click on connect